# BF3: How many points do you need to get a service star in vehicles?

Tags: battlefield-3

What are the points needed to get a service star in each vehicle?  I know it's 100 kills with the infantry weapons but I read that each vehicle has a different amount.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In vehicles, Service Stars are awarded for scoring the number of points which is equivalent to earning all the unlocks again. It's the same as the kits.

Here is the exact number for each applicable vehicle:

- **Tanks:** 100,000 points
- **Attack chopper:** 60,000 points
- **Scout chopper:** 48,000 points
- **Mobile AA:** 32,000 points
- **LAV:** 90,000 points
- **Jets:** 35,000 points

Answer (score 0):

Vehicle service stars unlock once you've unlocked all of the possible upgrades for that vehicle.
I think the final upgrade unlocks around 100,000 points and I think this final upgrade comes with the first service star.

After that, I think you might obtain another star every 100,000 points, but I haven't seen anything on the website to confirm this, it just says "when the next service star level is reached"

http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Service_Stars